# Ubuntu 16.04 showing wrong graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.04, intel

I went into System Settings > Details. It's showing that I have an Intel Haswell Mobile when I actually have a NVIDIA Geforce gt 730 and Intel graphics 4600. I tried installing NVIDIA drivers before, but got a black screen on restart.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I keep hearing people rave about how unstable 16.04 is. This is getting interesting.  In my experience, I have never experienced problem such as this with Nvidia drivers (At least with earlier versions of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Add the graphics drivers ppa and try the different nvidia drivers till you find the one that works. When I had that setup it was nvidia-358

Answer (score 0):

Running nvidia and an intel card requires you to take advantage of nVidia optimus, which *might* be on that card. (I don't know for sure) If you're installed off of stock, you'll run nouveau and need to fix a few things.

As a sidenote - I've had tremendous difficulty with 16.04 and nvidia cards - which is disappointing since the graphics drivers ppa for the GTX 1080 requires 16.04 and the 367 graphics package, as of this post.

1. Hold shift and boot your computer
2. When you get to the grub prompt, highlight ubuntu and press "E".
3. Add to the line starting with linux: " nouveau.modeset=0"
4. Press F10 to boot to console
5. Run these commands: (((DISCLAIMER: BACK UP YOUR SYSTEM FIRST)))

   sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-prime bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
6. If that doesn't work - you can try any other flavor of the drivers above 340, like 352, 361, or the meta-package nvidia-current. Older = more stable, newer = more features.

When you restart, if you get to the desktop - run "nvidia-settings" from the command line, or by typing "Nvidia" into the search bar. You should be able to select your primary card.

**ALSO: YOUR BIOS/CMOS MAY HAVE SETTINGS WHICH EXPLICITLY TELL YOUR MOTHERBOARD TO PREFER ONBOARD OR OFFBOARD GRAPHICS. CHECK THESE SETTINGS.**

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm quite new to Linux this is the output on step 5 http://pastebin.com/RZZnrQma

Comment: Run the command listed and give the output